# How to refer to member of a union from within the union?

Tags: c, member, unions

I'm trying to do the following:

```
struct AlignedBuffer {
    union
    {
        unsigned int n[4];
        unsigned char b[sizeof(n)];
    };
};
```

Its producing:

```
$ gcc -g3 -O1 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra test.c -o test.exe
test.c:13:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
        unsigned char b[sizeof(n)];
```

Is there a way to refer to members of a union from within the union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn’t allow you to do that, the operand of `sizeof` must be either a parenthesized type-name (which `n` clearly isn’t in your example) or an expression (a *unary-expression* in the C grammar), which the member of a union also isn’t.

You can do one of the following to not hard-code the size:

```
unsigned char b[sizeof(union { unsigned int n[4]; })];
unsigned char b[sizeof(unsigned int[4])];
```

In a comment to another answer you mentioned alignment concerns as the reason to do this, so maybe that’s of some interest to you: Memory allocated by `malloc` etc. is always suitably aligned for all types.

Comment: Thanks mafso. That's pretty ugly :) Also, the memory is stack based, not heap based. But I did not know malloc'd memory is aligned for all types. Is that all types, or all *integral* types? Will it be aligned for a float or double?

Comment: C99 7.20.3 p1 (slightly different in C11 7.22.3 p1) "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)." So, it _has to_ be aligned for `float` etc., e.g. `float *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);` would be UB otherwise, `malloc` has no idea to what pointer type the allocated storage will be assigned, in C11 terms, it must allocate an object with a _fundamental alignment requirement_.

Answer (score 1):

I like macros for this sort of thing.

```
typedef unsigned int my_number_t;
#define HOW_MANY_N 4
#define SIZE_OF_N sizeof(my_number_t)

struct AlignedBuffer {
    union
    {
        my_number_t n[HOW_MANY_N];
        unsigned char b[SIZE_OF_N * HOW_MANY_N];
    };
};
```

Or perhaps for more clarity and broader utility,

```
typedef unsigned int my_number_t;
#define SIZE_OF_N sizeof(my_number_t)
#define SIZE_OF_ALIGNED_BUFFER 16
#define HOW_MANY_N (SIZE_OF_ALIGNED_BUFFER / SIZE_OF_N)

struct AlignedBuffer {
    union
    {
        my_number_t n[HOW_MANY_N];
        unsigned char b[SIZE_OF_ALIGNED_BUFFER];
    };
};
```